# Installing local packages with Python virtualenv --system-site-packages

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I know this topic has been beat to death but I have not been able to find a solution to the problem I'm having on SO or elsewhere, so I suspect that there may be a bug somewhere in my system.

I am on an older RHEL 6 platform with Python 3.4. I am developing an application that will run on this platform that uses Qt. I've installed all of the relevant libraries via `yum` (e.g. `qt-devel`, `pyqt4-devel`, etc.) and now want to install my application package as an "editable" package using `pip install -e mypkg`. I also have a couple of dependency requirements that are not on `yum` and must be installed via `pip`.

What I would like to do is create a virtualenv that "inherits" the system packages installed via `yum` but allows me to `pip install` my own packages into a virtualenv directory in my home directory.

From my Googling it looks like the best way to do this is to create a virtual env with the system's site packages directory:

```sh
$ python3 -m venv --system-site-packages ~/venv
```

However, when I try to install a package to this virtualenv's site-packages directory, it attempts to install it under `/usr/lib` and I get a `Permission denied` error.

So it appears that the `--system-site-packages` option makes my virtualenv completely share the site-packages directory from my system instead of using it as a "base", where further packages can be layered on top.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079607/make-virtualenv-inherit-specific-packages-from-your-global-site-packages/19459977) states that using `pip install -I` should do what I want, but that does not appear to be the case:

```sh
(venv) $ pip3 install -I bitstring
...
error: could not create '/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bitstring.py': Permission denied
```

Comment: Did you activated the virtual env before trying to use pip again?

Comment: @marcanuy Yes, I attempted to indicate that with the `(venv)` in my prompt string

Comment: Are you certain you need to configure the virtual environment to use system packages? I seem to recall that packages installed via `yum` or `apt` are available in virtual envs even without enabling system packages (much to my surprise at the time). I would at least test.

Comment: @jpmc26 That does seem reasonable, but alas I don't think that is the case: `>>> import sys; print(sys.path)` shows `['', '/usr/lib64/python34.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.4', '/usr/lib64/python3.4/plat-linux', '/usr/lib64/python3.4/lib-dynload', '$HOME/venv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages', '$HOME/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages']`, which is missing `/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages`

Comment: @GregAnders No, no. Just try importing the module. E.g., `from PyQt4 import QtGui`. If it doesn't work, it doesn't, but my recollection is that it does (at least in some cases). Perhaps it gets installed to one of the other locations in your list.

Comment: @jpmc26 I did try it with numpy (also installed via yum) and got `ImportError: No module named 'numpy'`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Create the virtual environment without the `--system-site-packages` switch. After the environment was created go to the folder the environment was created in. It should have a file `pyvenv.cfg`. Edit this file. It has (among other text) a line

```
include-system-site-packages = false
```

Change this line to:

```
include-system-site-packages = true
```

Activate the environment. Module installations will now go to the virtual environment and the system site packages are visible too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40989759/8676953 might also be a good answer as it provides the link to the corresponding issue

Comment: How can I set some only some libraries to be shared?

Answer (score 5):

With Python 3.8, it seems `--system-site-packages` work as expected:

```
python3 -m venv --system-site-packages myProject
cat myProject/pyvenv.cfg 

home = /usr/bin
include-system-site-packages = true
version = 3.8.5
```

After installation `astroid, isort, wrapt`, I got:

```
pip list -v
Package                Version              Location                                                Installer
---------------------- -------------------- ------------------------------------------------------- ---------
apturl                 0.5.2                /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages                                   
astroid                2.4.2                /home/to/no/MR/auto-gen/lib/python3.8/site-packages pip      
isort                  5.6.4                /home/to/no/MR/auto-gen/lib/python3.8/site-packages pip      
jedi                   0.15.2               /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages                                   
keyring                18.0.1               /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages                                   
wrapt                  1.12.1               /home/to/no/MR/auto-gen/lib/python3.8/site-packages pip
```

Already installed 'system' packages are taken from `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` while locally (venv) installed packages from: `/home/to/no/MR/auto-gen/lib/python3.8/site-packages`